# How to use BestOf2NearestMatcher matching mask

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am playing around with OpenCV 3.0 and their [panorama sample](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp).

It works and now I want to understand and optimize it step by step for my usecase.
Intel has published an [article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-panorama-stitching) which fits to my need pretty good.

They say the matching can be improved by comparing only adjacent images.

The following code:

```
 vector<MatchesInfo> pairwise_matches;     
 BestOf2NearestMatcher matcher(try_cuda, match_conf);
 matcher(features, pairwise_matches);
 matcher.collectGarbage();
```

should be changed to:

```
vector<MatchesInfo> pairwise_matches;
BestOf2NearestMatcher matcher(try_cuda, match_conf);
Mat matchMask(features.size(),features.size(),CV_8U,Scalar(0));
for (int i = 0; i < num_images -1; ++i)
{
    matchMask.at<char>(i,i+1) =1;
}
matcher(features, pairwise_matches,matchMask);
matcher.collectGarbage();
```

But this does not work because matcher() requires a `UMat` in OpenCV 3.0 and `UMat` does not have an `at()` function.

I also tried:

```
matcher(features, pairwise_matches,matchMask.getUMat(ACCESS_READ ));
```

but this also does not work.

I whould be great if someone could explain how to use the Matcher with a mask or could migrate this to OpenCV 3.0 .

Comment: what do you mean by `getUMat` doesn't work? a compile time error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BestOf2NearestRangeMatcher` with `range_width=2` which should be faster than using masks as the inner loop will be shorter, see [the code here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/stitching/src/matchers.cpp#L667).

Comment: Thx I'll check that out.